# keras model output vector of one hot vectors, is it possible? are there any alternatives if not?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, one-hot-encoding

So I have an output vector of `dim=7` and 4 possible classes for each position, so my question is, is it possible to feed the keras model a vector of one hot vectors, where each position of the vector is a one hot vector? something like this `[[1000],[1000],[0100],[0010],[0001],[0001],[0010]]`.
If this is not possible are there any alternatives?

Comment: Yes it is possible, what makes you think it would not be possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your output of your model to be like that when your `model = keras.models.Model(...)`, the answer is **not possible** because the output that you provide (which is like a step respond "[1000] => [0000]") will have a gradient of infinity at step and 0 at other point.

What people do is to create a model that give distribution over different action and select the highest probability as predicted value and using cross entropy loss to optimize the model. For example, from your output `[1,0,0,0]` you will have something like `[0.9,0.01,0.01,0.08]` instead. Then you can pick first instance as predicted value. This will make sure that your model have gradient at all point.

So if you really want your model to have `dim = 7` and 4 different value, you can create output size of `28 = 7*4` with sigmoid activation, then pick first 4 as your dimension 1 (maybe using something like `np.argmax(output[0:4])`) and so on.